# How to add typing hints of **kwargs?

Tags: python, typing, keyword-argument, pylance

Here is an example:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, a=1, b=2, c=3):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, d=4, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.d = d
```

`B` adds one argument `d` and passes all key arguments to the super class `A`. The typing hint of `B()` shown by pylance is `(d: int = 4, **kwargs: Unknown) -> None`, How to add typing hint to `**kwargs`, that can make pylance knows the arguments is `(d: int = 4, a: int = 1, b: int = 2, c: int = 3) -> None`?

Comment: I do not have pylance installed so I cannot test this, but did you try `def __init__(self, a:int=1, b:int=2, c:int=3):`

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit of search and I found [this thread](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/270) and as far as I can tell there's no easy way to do it for now, even after [PEP-612](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/)